# stripe checkout doesn't validate required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, stripe-payments

`Stripe checkout` is not validating `required` input fields.

required field:

```
<input type="tel" name="appointment[patient_phone]" id="appointment_patient_phone" required="required" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

When I click on the `stripe` button, the `stripe checkout popup` appears and form is not validated.

So I tried and add a custom validator but `stopPropagation` is not working as the `stripe checkout popup` still pops up after `alert` and `stopPropagation` is called

```
function validateAppointmentForm() {

  var validateForm = function(event) {
    debugger;
    var phone = $('#appointment_patient_phone').val();
    if (!phone) {
      alert("Phone number is required.");
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  var watchStripeButton = function() {
    debugger;
    $("#new-appt-stripe-button").on("click", validateForm);
  }

  debugger;
  watchStripeButton();

}
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) here instead. This allows you to have your own button and add validation to your form before opening Checkout.

When the customer clicks on your button to pay and enter his card details, you'll detect some fields are not filled properly or have an invalid value and display an error. If the form validates you can then call `handler.open()` in the click handler.